# I am trying to install Squid Proxy using 'make' and 'make install command'. However, getting the error : -Werror=stringop-truncation

Tags: c, squid

```
smblib-util.c: In function 'SMB_Negotiate':
smblib-util.c:400:9: error: 'strncpy' output may be truncated copying 79 bytes from a string of length 79 [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
         strncpy(p, Con_Handle -> Svr_PDom, sizeof(Con_Handle -> Svr_PDom) - 1);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
smblib-util.c:423:9: error: 'strncpy' output may be truncated copying 79 bytes from a string of length 79 [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
         strncpy(p, Con_Handle -> Svr_PDom, sizeof(Con_Handle -> Svr_PDom) - 1);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
smblib-util.c: In function 'SMB_TreeConnect':
smblib-util.c:537:5: error: 'strncpy' specified bound 129 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
     strncpy(tree -> path, path, sizeof(tree -> path));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
smblib-util.c:538:5: error: 'strncpy' specified bound 20 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
     strncpy(tree -> device_type, device, sizeof(tree -> device_type));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [Makefile:765: smblib-util.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sayand/Downloads/squid-3.5.28-20190909-r8e657e8/lib/smblib'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1032: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sayand/Downloads/squid-3.5.28-20190909-r8e657e8/lib'
make: *** [Makefile:569: install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: PS: I am not a linux nor a C expert.

Comment: Why do you need to build a 2-year-old version of Squid from source?

Comment: The purpose was to install squid and integrate it with Symantec DLP. Hence, following the steps mentioned in the document.  https://techdocs.broadcom.com/content/dam/broadcom/techdocs/symantec-security-software/information-security/data-loss-prevention/generated-pdfs/Symantec_DLP_15.7_Squid_Integration_Guide.pdf

Comment: Which distribution is this on? Unless you know what you're doing, you should not necessarily be compiling and installing packages sidestepping your distro's package manager. For instance, Ubuntu 18.04 has a prepackaged `squid` and it seems to be compiled with `--enable-icap-client` as the instructions in your PDF say.

Comment: I am compiling it on a RHEL 8

Comment: If you can let me know how can I enable icap client on an installed squid client using the 'yum install squid' command in a CentOS or RHEL.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used CentOS or RHEL. Looks like someone else's had this problem too, but I don't have a support subscription to be able to see the rest here. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2810361

Comment: I tried with Squid v5 but no luck. The above mentioned error seems to disappear but after 'Make Install' I don't see any service getting registered for Squid.

Comment: Complete manual installation is usually a recipe for disaster. Download the source package and rpmbuild that. If that works, change the configuration flags and rpm build it again.